# How can I change a .scrollToTop () to a scrollToBottom () in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my code to load some data when the client is at the bottom of the page, but I load it when I scroll up. How can I change this in my code?

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
                    getData();
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Allaiks did answer the question.
I suspect if you are developing online that caching is the issue you can't see the update.
Try to improve your question or add more code and html if it didn't work for you.

Here is a jsfiddle:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if($(window).scrollTop() >= (($(document).height() - $(window).height())))
                   alert("This is the bottom of the page!");
                    
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<div style="width:200px; height:2000px; background:#b2000b;">Some div</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not understand it, the alert jumps me when I only scroll down.

Comment: I understand you need to run `getData()` when you reach the bottom of the page.. correct? replace `alert()` with `getData()`

Comment: Try to add more code, are you trying to show some data in your page footer for example? only when user reach there?

Comment: are you doing it while some page caching is there? Are you sure the update is getting refreshed?

Comment: yeah sure, I don't understand it

Comment: You didn't pick an answer! dose this mean you didn't find one? Let me know to improve my answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition into

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
```

So each time the user scrolls, the page checks whether they have reached the bottom of the page.

Comment: It does not work, it keeps loading when it returns to the top of the page.